# Search an item by name passed in the URL on Code Igniter and HTACCESS

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

friends,

I am developing an application that has some basic controllers, like `user` (for creating and signing in), `page` (for creating, listing), `home` (the main page of the website) and others.

I am using Code Igniter as PHP framework and I am really enjoying it. But as a beginner I have a few questions...

When I go to localhost/ci/ I am redirected to the ´home´ page as I defined. There is an `index` method that is responsible for controlling this request and it serves the user with the main page.

Ok. But I wanted some pages to be displayed as I enter their names after the domain, for example: **localhost/ci/page-to-be-displayed**, then the controller should check whether it is a page or not and then display its content.

**localhost/ci/page/page-to-be-displayed** is also accepted

How can I achieve this? If i go to `localhost/ci/page/page-to-be-displayed`, for example, it will try to load this method `page-to-be-displayed` and a 404 error will be triggered (since CI is trying to find a method with that name in the ´page´ controller)

Thank you in advance

**@dit**

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|styles)
RewriteCond $1 !\.(js|css|html?g)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use CodeIgniter Routes.

In your Route.php

```
$route['page/(:any)'] = "your-controller/$1";
```

Note: You can use `(:any),(:num) or regex`

Also, don't forget to remove the `index.php` from the config.php file.
[CodeIgniter API Doc](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)